# Regular expression that matches specific css declaration, with or without optional semicolon

Tags: regex

I need to smite specific css declarations from inline style attributes using plain old JavaScript. Regular expressions seem like a good tool. And indeed, this does it:

```
#font-family.*?;#
```

However, the trailing semicolon is optional when there's only one deceleration or for the last deceleration in a series of them.

I've tried a number of things, for example:

```
#font-family.*?[;]##
#font-family.*?;?##
#font-family.*?;{0,1}##
```

All fail to do The Right Thing, which given the following strings:

```
style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size:10em; font-weight:normal;"
style="font-size:10em; font-weight:normal; font-family: sans-serif "
style="font-size:10em; font-weight:normal; font-family: sans-serif"
style="font-family: sans-serif;"
style="font-family: sans-serif"
```

would return:

```
style="font-size:10em; font-weight:normal;"
style="font-size:10em; font-weight:normal;"
style="font-size:10em; font-weight:normal;"
style=""
style=""
```

respectively.

How can I modify my regex to include the case where the trailing semicolon is missing?

Comment: What is *The Right Thing*?

Comment: .* captures the semicolon, something you aren't telling us?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Heh. Great question. Sorry for not being more specific. I'll update the question.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson So it would seem. I've updated the questions with example inputs and expected results; that should answer your question. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Try `\s*font-family:[^;"]*;?\s*`

Comment: Jut checked on Rubular and @WiktorStribiżew got it.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson: I posted an answer, but note that is not guaranteed to work with arbitrary input. It will affect `font-family:` everywhere in the input string regardless whether it is in a text or a tag or attribute text.

Comment: Shrugs, that's the problem when you use Regex on markup.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson Indeed. Thanks!

Comment: The user has found another, very similar, use case. I've been messing around with it, but I'm not doing well. Anybody up for another challenge? If so, what's the procedure? Update the original question? As I say, it's very close to those examples. Thank you!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for your strings posted, the following regex will work:

```
\s*font-family:[^;"]*;?\s*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rIOX9H/1)

**Details**:

- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `font-family:`  - a literal text
- `[^;"]*`  - zero or more chars other thna `;` and `"`
- `;?` - an optional `;`
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces

Comment: Great answer! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Would you consider `font-family[^;]*;?(?>")` ? 
I'm not familiar with css, but it looks like you want to capture one of the `;`-separated (not `;`-terminated) specifications in a `"..."`-string, and you don't want to match the closing `"`. You avoid the latter by having a lookahead (nonconsuming) match for the `"`.